# jQuery: passing a variable to a click hander for dynamically created DOM element

Tags: jquery, variables, click, selector, dynamically-generated

I am attempting to attach an event handler to a dynamically created DOM element in the following way:

```
var createdElement = $('<a>', {
    click: function (data) {
        alert("click");
    }
});
```

This works as expected, but now I want to pass a variable to the click function. Can anyone suggests how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean pass a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thecodeparadox's answer works in the general case, but always passes the same value to the `click` handler, regardless of the `<a>` element on which it was triggered.

If you want the value to depend on the clicked element, you can call [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) on the element itself:

```
var createdElement = $("<a>").on("click", {
    yourData: "something"
}, function(event) {
    alert("Data is " + event.data.yourData);
}).appendTo("body");
```

However, the code above uses a different syntax than the one in your question. If you want to keep defining the `click` handler in a property/event map, you can use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to associate a value with the element once and for all:

```
var createdElement = $("<a>", {
    click: function() {
        alert("Data is " + $(this).data("yourData"));
    }
}).data("yourData", "something").appendTo("body");
```

(Note that I added calls to `appendTo("body")` so the new element becomes part of the DOM and the `click` event gets a chance to be triggered. Feel free to ignore this if you're adding the element to the DOM later in your code.)

Comment: Thanks Frédéric, this is exactly what I needed. Can you recommend any good tutorials on jQuery syntax?

Comment: @Ben, the documentation has a [Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) section. Did you check it out?

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that. I'll check it out.